# How to make a function that is done every 24 hours without stopping the whole program with time.sleep() for that time?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a Discord bot that stores a deadline for a user in a message channel. After the deadline ends, I want the bot to notify the moderators so they can deal with it.

Everything for the bot besides that is already done. My idea for this issue is to just have a function that checks the channel with deadlines every 24 hours and finds the same date on it as the current date and takes out the userid (which is also stored in said message).
I'm open to other solutions for this problem.

I've read up and Googled a bunch. It, at least, seems like to me that `time.sleep()` and `schedule.every` will stop my whole program for that time, but maybe I'm wrong about the schedule thing, because I tried to implement it into my code, but I got no idea how to make it work. I have only a week of Python experience here, bear with me.

Here is pretty much my whole code if it helps (without the bot token part, of course)

```
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
from discord.utils import get
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '%')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(game=Game(name='with nuclear waste'))
    print('Ready, bitch')


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if ' has sent an application to become a full fledged FRICK' in reaction.message.content:
        Name = reaction.message.content.split('#')
        usid = reaction.message.content.split('=')
        usid1 = usid[1].split(' ')
        user =reaction.message.server.get_member(usid1[0])
        msg = reaction.message.content.split('?')
        eventcode = str (msg[1])
        cont = str(msg[0])
        kakapoopoo = '@' + usid1[0]
        #await client.send_message(user, 'test')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='FeelsBadMan'):
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), Name[0] + ' has attented 1 event.')
            await client.edit_message(reaction.message, cont + '?01')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='veetsmug'):
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), Name[0] + ' has attented 2 events.')
            await client.edit_message(reaction.message, cont + '?10')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='POGGERS'):
            await client.edit_message(reaction.message, cont + '?11')
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), Name[0] + ' has attented 3 events.')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS'):
            role1 = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.server.roles, name='Pending Frick')
            await client.remove_roles(user, role1)
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), user.mention + ' has attented 4 events and is now a ***FRICK***.\n@here')
            role2 = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.server.roles, id='561087733834186754')
            await client.add_roles(user, role2)
            await client.send_message(user, 'You are now a full fledged ***FRICK***')
            await client.delete_message(reaction.message)
    elif 'To approve screenshot react with :HYPERS: to dissaprove react with :FeelsBadMan:' in reaction.message.content:
        cunt = reaction.message.content.split('#')
        name = cunt[0]
        idududu = reaction.message.content.split('?')
        peepee = idududu[1]
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' + peepee)
        idud = peepee.split('\nThe events the user has attented before are:')
        usid = idud[0]
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' + usid)
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' +str(usid))
        user=await client.get_user_info(usid)
        event = reaction.message.content.split('has attented a ')
        eventu = event[1]
        evento = eventu.split('Screenshot:')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS'):
            await client.send_message(user, 'Your screenshot has been approved')
            await client.delete_message(reaction.message)
            async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='561667365927124992'), limit = 100):
                #await client.send_message(user, 'test')
                if name in message.content:
                    if ' eventcode?00' in message.content:
                        await client.send_message(user, 'You have attented 1 event')
                        emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='FeelsBadMan')
                        await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
                        await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='562607755358371840'), str(usid) + ' ' + str(evento[0]))
                    elif ' eventcode?01' in message.content:
                        await client.send_message(user, 'You have attented 2 events')
                        emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='veetsmug')
                        await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
                        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='562607755358371840'), limit = 100):
                            if usid in message.content:
                                cont = message.content
                                await client.edit_message(message, cont + ', ' + str(evento[0]))
                    elif ' eventcode?10' in message.content:
                        await client.send_message(user, 'You have attented 3 events')
                        emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='POGGERS')
                        await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
                        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='562607755358371840'), limit = 100):
                            if usid in message.content:
                                cont = message.content
                                await client.edit_message(message, cont + ', ' + str(evento[0]))
                    elif ' eventcode?11' in message.content:
                        emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS')
                        await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
                        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='562607755358371840'), limit = 100):
                            if usid in message.content:
                                await client.delete_message(message)
        elif reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='FeelsBadMan'):
            await client.send_message(user, 'Your screenshot has not been approved')
            await client.delete_message(reaction.message)



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == '%start':
        if "561047714230435871" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=21)
            author = message.author
            mes = str(author) + ' has sent an application to become a full fledged FRICK id ='+ str(message.author.id) + ' Deadline+' +str(deadline.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + ' eventcode?00'
            emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS')
            await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
            role = get(message.server.roles, id='561055432748302336')
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
            await client.send_message(client.get_channel('561667365927124992'), mes)
            await client.send_message(message.author, '***You have entered the Frickling program!**\n\nTo become a full fledged Frick you must attend 4 guild/alliance events. Please provide screensots to the bot proving that you have attented them by using %attended command followed by a screenshot **LINK** and the name of the activity.\n\n Example: %attented https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530909412320083969/558085258164305921/guild_event_2.jpg fame farm')
            role = get(message.server.roles, name='Frickling')
            await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
        elif "561055432748302336" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel,'Seems like you already started the application process for becoming a full fledged Frick')
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel,'Seems like you do not have the permisssions to use me.\n\nIt might be because your application for Frickling has not yet been approved or you are already a full fledged Frick')

    elif message.content == 'Tell that bot to get lost':
        if message.author == message.server.get_member('336858563064496130'):
            await client.send_message(message.channel,'Get lost, stupid bot')

    elif message.content == 'Tell Meatcup to get lost':
        if message.author == message.server.get_member('336858563064496130'):
            user = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.server.members, id ='331864154803666945')
            await client.send_message(user, 'Get lost, Meatcup')

    elif message.content == '%cunt':
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'Yes, my master?')
        emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS')
        await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)

    elif message.content == '%testfrick':
        if "561087733834186754" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel,'You are a frick')
        else:
             await client.send_message(message.channel,'Error')

    elif message.content == '%testpend':
        if "561055432748302336" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel,'You are pending')
        else:
             await client.send_message(message.channel,'Error')

    elif '%attended' in message.content and message.author.id != '560634369094582302':
        author = message.author
        authid = message.author.id
        cunt = 0
        msg = message.content.split(' ',2)
        if len(msg) > 2:
            emoji = get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS')
            await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
            for i in client.servers:
                for x in i.roles:
                    if x.id == '561055432748302336':
                        async for message in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id='562607755358371840'), limit = 100):
                            if authid in message.content:
                                eventu = message.content.split(' ',1)
                                cunt = 1
                                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='560679934209687552'), str(author) + ' has attented a ' + msg[2] + '\nScreenshot:' + msg[1] + '\nTo approve screenshot react with :HYPERS: to dissaprove react with :FeelsBadMan:\nUserid?'+authid + '\nThe events the user has attented before are: ' + str(eventu[1]))
                        if cunt == 0:
                            await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='560679934209687552'), str(author) + ' has attented a ' + msg[2] + '\nScreenshot:' + msg[1] + '\nTo approve screenshot react with :HYPERS: to dissaprove react with :FeelsBadMan:\nUserid?'+ authid)
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.author,'Error. You did not provide the name of the event or you only provided the name of the event.')
```

Comment: Can you share snippets of your source code?

Comment: all of the code

Comment: Have you thought of using system job scheduling, i.e. `cron`?

Comment: You can use cron api to do this without monitoring in python https://crontab.guru/#0_*/24_*_*_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asynchronous python, when non-blocking sleeping is required, you can use the method `asyncio.sleep(n)`, n being the number of seconds you want the method to sleep for. So a basic async method that sleeps once every 24 hours would look something like this:

```
async def daily_task():
    print('This method will NOT block')
    await asyncio.sleep(24*60*60)
```

EDIT: Thanks go to Benjin, who pointed out that I forgot to `await` the sleep.

Comment: do I have to continuosly call such a function for it to work?
EDIT: I'm stupid and forgot to .run it lol

Comment: I'm in 3.6 Would the code I have no work if I upgraded to 3.7 so I could use asyncio.run?

Comment: You can do `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_function_name())` for  python `3.6`

Comment: `asyncio.sleep` is a coroutine and needs to be awaited. `await asyncio.sleep(24*60*60)`

Answer (score 1):

Threads will let you work "simultaneously" on 2 things (or more...). When one thread will sleep, another thread can do "the rest"

Comment: As I said, I only have a week of python experience, so please elaborate on what thread means